# insert new data from csv to already existing postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

this part of my code is for looping through a folder and import multiple csv file to postgresql database:

```
import psycopg2

file_names = [
    'C:/john/database_files'
]

con = psycopg2.connect(database="xxxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx", host="xxxx")

for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_in:
        next(file_in)
        with con.cursor() as cur:
            cur.copy_from(file_in, "table_name", columns=('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'), sep=",")
        con.commit()

con.close()
```

if there are new csv files of the same column headers are created later on, I want to import the  data from the new csv files only, so that the new data is added to the same data table in the database (not overwrite). For example, if a new csv file of 10 rows is created, and my current database has 100 rows, the updated data table will have 110 rows.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to process the files only once, the common way is to move then to a different folder (say `done`) after successful processing. If you additionally use an `error` folder to store the files raising an error, you can later come and analyze what went wrong. This technic has been used at least from the 70' with the name *spool* ;-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code to create a text file containing list of all the indexed files. This will allow the code to read only the unseen csv files.

```
import os
import psycopg2

dir_name = 'C:/john/database_files'
processed_files = []

# Load processed_files from a file, if it exists
try:
    with open('processed_files.txt', 'r') as f:
        processed_files = f.read().splitlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

con = psycopg2.connect(database="xxxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx", host="xxxx")

# Loop over all CSV files in the directory
for file_name in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if file_name.endswith('.csv') and file_name not in processed_files:
        with open(os.path.join(dir_name, file_name), 'r') as file_in:
            next(file_in)
            with con.cursor() as cur:
                cur.copy_from(file_in, "table_name", columns=('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'), sep=",")
            con.commit()

        # Mark this file as processed
        processed_files.append(file_name)

con.close()

# Save the list of processed files
with open('processed_files.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file_name in processed_files:
        f.write("%s\n" % file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This would work for me. A separate question - I read that newer version of postgre supports "upsert", like insert.... do nothing if exist. Can that be applied to the problem here?

Comment: The upsert command updates if a row is already present which might work for you but you will have the overhead of reading every csv file all the time which is not efficient and through the highlighted approach, this overhead is avoided. You can check out the docs for more details on the upsert command https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT